# python trouble using DateOffset

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

below is my df

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
                   'Year': ['03/03/2021', '22/01/2060', '04/03/2021', '22/07/2068'],
                    'offset' : [1, 9, 8, 1]
})
```

I was a 3rd column which will give me a new date taking into the offset (which is in years). i.e. the new column will have values

```
['03/03/2022', '22/01/2069', '04/03/2029', '22/07/2069']
```

I tried using

```
df['ExpiryDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Year']) + pd.DateOffset(months=df.offset)
```

but getting error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.map()` on the column and then `.dt.strftime` to change format:

```
df['ExpiryDate'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Year']) + df['offset'].map(lambda y: pd.offsets.DateOffset(months=y))
df['ExpiryDate'] = df['ExpiryDate'].dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

Column output:

```
0    03/03/2022
1    22/01/2069
2    03/04/2029
3    22/07/2069
```